# Word count by day in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to do a word count by day and could use some help. 
My goal is to make a csv that has one date row like this:
[image]

I have gotten this far in my pandas dataframe. Notice there are multiple rows for the same date. I need the top 5 most commonly used words per day.

[image]

I'm pretty sure I can handle the csv part. I just need a new dataframe that looks more like the goal one on top. I would really appreciate the help!
Thanks!

Comment: What is your original input? You can work with where you've got, but I suspect you could also do better earlier

Comment: The original input is a list of strings that were from tweets I scraped. After putting it through the stopwords etc. cleanup process, this is my current result.